# Crystallography: The shape of axial divergent profiles

Tags: crystals, crystallography

I don't know if crystallography related topics go into this stack exchange, so sorry if that's wrong here.

My question concerns the characteristic shape of axial divergent powder patterns. According to Dinnerbier and Billinge, *Powder Diffraction Theory and Practice*, RSC Publishing, **2008** can an axially divergent reflection be decomposed into various positions:

[image]

Here *φ1* marks the most divergent part of the incoming X-rays. What I can't find however is how this shape is related to the divergence itself. So why does it look like this 'fin' with a strong fronting-effect once the beam diverges? My idea would be the following. As the diffraction on the sample creates a scattering-cone where the circular base holds the information on the intensity we will only see some part of it, a conic section where the cone itersects with the detector slit. So the overall and still arbitrary intensity (y-axis, not area under the curve) should be the arc segment the slit actually detects. But if I move the detector slit (that is orthogonal to the cone's direction) parallel to this direction, so I intersect at a point closer or further away from the scattered sample I should expect the overall intensity in this arc segment to be smaller once it is further away as the same intensity should be spread over a larger circular path and therefore a segment has comparably lower intensity the further it is away from the source. That is at least how I would imagine it to happen.
So if some parts of the incoming beam scatter further away from the scattering center, so axial divergence happens the cone should travel a longer distance compared to the central part of the incoming X-rays (focus point). So if it intersects with the detector the main non-divergent part of the beam will have a smaller cone and higher intensity density than the divergent one. If both have a rather similar conic intersection (leaving curvature for a second) it should have a relatively lower intensity for the more divergent part of the beam.

Is that reasoning somewhat logical or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: The people over at [Chemistry SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) might have a better chance of answering this.